# My call is automatically cut into 60 sec. how can fix this and how can i increse the call limit?

Tags: laravel, twilio

I am using twilio for my in app calling between customer and driver. My call is automatically cut into 60 sec. how can fix this and how can i increse the call limit?

I try to enable the 24-hours maximum duration in twilio setting. But it does not work for me, how cam i increase the call duration.